# How can I get a html tags' Computed Style values ,then set the values to "style"

Tags: javascript, css

example:
Computed Style's value =>

```
#myLayer {position: absolute;width: 200px;height: 100px;color: #0000ff;}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id='myLayer '></div>
```

which I want to like this:

```
 <div id='myLayer ' style='  position: absolute;width: 200px;height: 100px;color: #0000ff;'></div>
```

Comment: Dare I ask... why?

Comment: What is it you're asking exactly?

Comment: I want to get all the elements' Computed Style on the page, and then assign the Computed Style value to the element's "style" attribute。

Answer (score 0):

If the result of computed style is stored like this:

```
var style = "#myLayer {position: absolute;width: 200px;height: 100px;color: #0000ff;}"
```

You could use the `.cssText` property to set it. You'd just need to remove the selector and brackets.

```
style = style.slice(style.indexOf("{") + 1, style.lastIndexOf("}"));

document.getElementById("myLayer").style.cssText = style;
```

Comment: OK.thanks for your reply.And  I need to get all the tags on a page,and replace the arribute "style" with the Computed style value